# Failed to start service Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service / Faulting application name: FabricHost.exe

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am following this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-get-started/ to setup Service Fabric on my Windows 8.1 machine. But when I run .\DevClusterSetup.ps1 I get the following error

```
Create node configuration succeeded
Starting service FabricHostSvc. This may take a few minutes...
Start-Service : Failed to start service 'Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service (FabricHostSvc)'.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1:167 char:1
+ Start-Service FabricHostSvc -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

WARNING: Could not start FabricHostSvc
```

This shows up in the event log as

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          11/6/2015 11:35:02 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      IN************
Description:
Faulting application name: FabricHost.exe, version: 4.0.1427.9490, time stamp: 0x55a4c9d5
Faulting module name: FabricHost.exe, version: 4.0.1427.9490, time stamp: 0x55a4c9d5
Exception code: 0xc0000602
Fault offset: 0x0000000000072991
Faulting process id: 0x1e80
Faulting application start time: 0x01d118585c7f3a7b
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\FabricHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\FabricHost.exe
Report Id: 50b94631-844c-11e5-bf04-f01faf5113dc
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-11-06T06:05:02.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>253055</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>I*******</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>FabricHost.exe</Data>
    <Data>4.0.1427.9490</Data>
    <Data>55a4c9d5</Data>
    <Data>FabricHost.exe</Data>
    <Data>4.0.1427.9490</Data>
    <Data>55a4c9d5</Data>
    <Data>c0000602</Data>
    <Data>0000000000072991</Data>
    <Data>1e80</Data>
    <Data>01d118585c7f3a7b</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\FabricHost.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\FabricHost.exe</Data>
    <Data>50b94631-844c-11e5-bf04-f01faf5113dc</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I have tried

- reinstall the Service Fabric SDK
- loadctr /R
- reinstall Windows Azure SDK and then the Service Fabric SDK

I do see that FabricSetup.exe gets launched in the background again and again till I run CleanCluster.ps1. The SfDevCluster folder is created and under that the Manifests and Log folders are created.

Anyone run into this issue ?

Windows 8.1
Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition
Windows Azure SDK 2.7.1

Comment: I have the same issue.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin>FabricHost.exe
Unhandled exception. (exception class std::system_error Common::ServiceBase::Run:154: StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW(ServiceTable))

Comment: Did you find a solution?